# Bootstrap 4 navbar appearing vertically not horizontally

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have built a Navbar exactly how it has been done on a tutorial yet somehow my navbar appears vertically when it should appear horizontally. Any ideas on how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class='container'>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class='nav-item'>
                <a class='nav-link' routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
                <a class='nav-link' routerLink="/documents" routerLinkActive="active">Docs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block dropdown-links">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="proposalDropdown" ngbDropdownToggle>
                        Proposals
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="proposalDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/proposals" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true}">Proposals</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/proposals/new" routerLinkActive="active">New Proposal</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you have included bootstrap to your page. Looks like you don't have any style. You need to either CDN or to download bootstrap and link the css.

Answer (score 11):

Add `navbar-toggleable-sm`(`md`/`lg`) to `nav` element to make it horizontal till `sm`, otherwise it would be render vertical every time.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">

   ....

</nav>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/13j82WtaBLmSShwRWKbY?p=preview)

Answer (score 11):

Bootstrap 4 requires you add **navbar-expand-md** to your opening nav classes otherwise it will be vertical ..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
```

You can replace the **md** with **xs**, **lg** or **sm** for different breakpoints.

[image]

[Go to Bootstrap 4 Navbar documentation and view the first example.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is to refer the bootstrap in the css

This example is for an application in Angular

1. Without bootstrap included the pagination looked as below

[image]

2. Include the bootstrap reference in the project

[image]

3. Now the pagination with bootstrap effect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Avoid adding classes with single quotations, add classes with double quotations instead.